# Free SMTP server?

Tags: smtp

I'm in need of sending thousands of E-Mails, and I have my E-Mail list ready but how do I find an SMTP server that can help me send these.-I also have a software ready to send these, all I need is the SMTP server. Google only offers 500, which is nowhere close to what I need.

Opinions?

Comment: Have you tried a cloud based service like sparkpost.com?

Answer (score 0):

For windows-servers search for "hmailserver" this contains a full featured smtp server

Comment: It needs to be able to send thousands of E-Mails, I hope this can.

Comment: it does have a outgoing mail queue so you can send as many mails as needed.. but if you try to send spam your server will be blacklisted and ip banned and no one will recieve any of your mails.